# Xstream how to avoid a field with specific value while marshaling

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I want to create an xml in the following format

```
<parm-list>
<param>
<NAME>somename</NAME>
<VALUE>somevalue</VALUE>
</param>
<param>
<NAME>somename</NAME>
<VALUE>somevalue</VALUE>
</param>
<param>
<NAME>somename</NAME>
<VALUE>somevalue</VALUE>
</param>
<param>
<NAME>somename</NAME>
<VALUE>somevalue</VALUE>
</param>
</param-list>
```

What can i do if i don't want  a `<PARAM>` field with specific  `<NAME>` in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I really don't think that Xstream is really appropriate for the task, it does seem to be possible.

You could implement your own converter similar to [one of those](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converters.html). If you take a look at [Converter](http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/Converter.html) interface, you'll see that you can easily skip an element by not writing anything to `HierarchicalStreamWriter`.

```
public class ParamConverter implements Converter{

    boolean canConvert(Class type){
        return Param.class.equals(type);
    }

    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context){
        Param param = (Param)source;
        if (NAME_TO_SKIP.equals(param.getName()){
            return;
        }
        // delegate to ReflectionConverter or something else appropriate.
    }   
}
```

To register converter simply call `xStram.registerConverter(new ParamConverter());`.

For more information please read [this tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html) on converters.